# Transforming text with 'sed' or 'awk'

Tags: sed, awk, transform

I have a very large input set that looks something like this:

```
Label: foo, Other text: text description...
   <insert label> Item: item description...
   <insert label> Item: item description...
Label: bar, Other text:...
   <insert label> Item:...
Label: baz, Other text:...
   <insert label> Item:...
   <insert label> Item:...
   <insert label> Item:...
...
```

I'd like to transform this to pull out the label name (e.g. `"foo"`) and replace the tag `"<insert label>"` on the following lines with the actual label.

```
Label: foo, Other text: text description...
   foo Item: item description...
   foo Item: item description...
Label: bar, Other text:...
   bar Item:...
Label: baz, Other text:...
   baz Item:...
   baz Item:...
   baz Item:...
...
```

Can this be done with sed or awk or other unix tool? If so, how might I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using `sed`:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## When line beginning with the 'label' string.
/^Label/ {
    ## Save content to 'hold space'.
    h   

    ## Get the string after the label (removing all other characters)
    s/^[^ ]*\([^,]*\).*$/\1/

    ## Save it in 'hold space' and get the original content
    ## of the line (exchange contents).
    x   

    ## Print and read next line.
    b   
}
###--- Commented this wrong behaviour ---###    
#--- G
#--- s/<[^>]*>\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\1/

###--- And fixed with this ---###
## When line begins with '<insert label>'
/<insert label>/ {
    ## Append the label name to the line.
    G   

    ## And substitute the '<insert label>' string with it.
    s/<insert label>\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\1/
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
Label: foo, Other text: text description...
   <insert label> Item: item description...
   <insert label> Item: item description...
Label: bar, Other text:...
   <insert label> Item:...
Label: baz, Other text:...
   <insert label> Item:...
   <insert label> Item:...
   <insert label> Item:...
```

Run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

And result:

```
Label: foo, Other text: text description...
    foo Item: item description...
    foo Item: item description...
Label: bar, Other text:...
    bar Item:...
Label: baz, Other text:...
    baz Item:...
    baz Item:...
    baz Item:...
```

Comment: Getting an error: `sed: 2: script.sed: invalid command code I`. Am I using a different version of `sed`?

Comment: @Manish: Yes. It is a GNU extension to ignore case of the string to match. Already modified the program to match (including case) the exact word.

Comment: Works now, but not if you have non-"<insert label>" lines in the file. I've changed your last line to `/<insert label>/!s/\n.*//;s/<insert label>\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\1/` to handle that. (Also, let's match "<insert label>" specifically, there may be other such "tags" in the file.)

Comment: Rather than change the last line, change the last two to: `/<insert label>/{G;s/<insert label>\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\1/}`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks everyone. All the answers did the trick. Sadly I can only accept one and this is the one I went with.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my label.awk file:

```
/^Label:/ {
    label = $2
    sub(/,$/, "", label)
}

/<insert label>/ {
    sub(/<insert label>/, label)
}

1
```

To invoke:

```
awk -f label.awk data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk '$1=="Label:" {label=$2; sub(/,$/, "", label);} 
     $1=="<insert" && $2=="label>" {$1=" "; $2=label;}
     {print $0;}' file
```

Comment: If you're anchoring the pattern, you might as well use `sub` instead of `gsub`. You don't need the line continuation inside single quotes.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thank you very much for your suggestions and making the Edit. Appreciate it.